# Shell Hive - Identify a column in entire Hive Database

Tags: bash, shell, hive, hiveql

The below code not go in loop if I change first line to hive -S -e 'show databases like `'abc_xyz%'`'|
Can you please help to fix this issue?`

````
hive -S -e 'show databases'|
    while read database
    do
       eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in $database'"|
       while read line
       do
    if eval "hive -S -e 'describe $database.$line'"| grep -q "<column_name>"; then
      output="Required table name: $database.$line"'\n';
    else
    output=""'\n';
    
    fi
    echo -e "$output"
     done
    done```
````

Comment: Actual Database number is more than 2000, if I filter by show databases like 'abc_xyz%' it will be only 50 Databases. pls let me know is there a way to achieve it in the above shell?

Comment: Are you running Hive version >= 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards in the [show databases command](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+ddl#LanguageManualDDL-Show) pattern can only be '*' for any character(s) or '|' for a choice for Hive < 4.0.0.

For example like this:

```
show databases like 'abc_xyz*|bcd_xyz*'
```

SQL-style patterns '%' for any character(s), and '_' for a single character work only since Hive 4.0.0